# How do you find the p-value for a uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, self-study, uniform-distribution

If I am given a uniform distribution U ~ Uniform[-3, 2], how do I find P(2X+6>4)? I'm not sure where to begin other than noting that -3 is the mean and 2 is the variance.

Comment: Those are not the mean and variance of a uniform distribution. You have confused that notation with the notation for a normal distribution, which is quite different. I would start by doing some algebra inside of the $P$ to get $P(x>-1)$. One you see that you’re solving for $P(x>-1)$, does the problem get easier? (It’s just some geometry, though I would suggest doing the calculus, if your class uses calculus, to get used to such calculations.) // The “p-value” you mention in the title is a specific meaning in statistics. While a p-value is a probability, it is a special kind of probability.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the reply. Ok now I understand - those values are a and b (i.e. the upper and lower bound of the uniform distribution) And therefore I assume we can do 3 * 1/5=0.6 which is the correct answer. I can also integrate f(x) from -1 to 2 also giving 0.6.

Comment: Looks good! If you believe you’ve solved the problem (I think you have), you might consider posting a self-answer.

Comment: What has any of this to do with p-values?